# Замена символов в строке ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как заменить все буквенные символы в строке на нули в результате запроса?
Нужно чтобы например 01_02_03_аю стало 01_02_03_00
Что-то подобное функции REPLACE(ex, [a-z][а-я], '0')

Comment: Посмотрите https://github.com/churupaha/RegexWrapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
declare @s nvarchar(100) =N'sdf1AbCD2ывалоКПsdf45sdf897'

while PATINDEX(N'%[a-zа-я]%', @s)>0
    set @s=STUFF(@s, PATINDEX(N'%[a-zа-я]%', @s),1, '0')

select @s
```

Результат: `000100002000000000045000897`